# Finding the pre-image of the set $\{ k \in\mathbb Z : \ k~\text{is even}\}$ under $ f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \ by \ f(n) = n^2 $

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Find the pre-image of the set $$\{ k \in\mathbb Z : \ k~\text{is even}\}$$ under $$ f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\text{ by }f(n) = n^2 $$
It's seen that $ f(-1)=f(1)=1 $ but $-1$ is not equal to $1$. Therefore, $f$ isn't injective. Now, $-2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, but there doesn't exist any element $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) =n^2=-2$. Therefore, $f$ isn't surjective. Hence, function $f$ is neither injective nor surjective. If $$\{ k \in \mathbb{Z}: \ k\ \text{is even}\} $$ then $ k=\{ \ldots, -6,-4,-2,2,4,6, \ldots\}$ and I got stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$f^{-1}\bigl(\{k\in\Bbb Z\mid k\text{ is even}\}\bigr)=\{k\in\Bbb Z\mid k\text{ is even}\}.$$In fact:

- if $k\in\Bbb Z$ is even, then $k^2$ is an even integer, and therefore $k\in f^{-1}\bigl(\{k\in\Bbb Z\mid k\text{ is even}\}\bigr)$;
- if $k\in\Bbb Z$ is odd,  then $k^2$ is and odd integer, and therefore $k\notin f^{-1}\bigl(\{k\in\Bbb Z\mid k\text{ is even}\}\bigr)$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.